# Somethings about Infineon BTN8962

Tags: motor, integrated-circuit, dc-motor, h-bridge, full-bridge

I want to design a BDC driving board with [Infineon BTN8962](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTN8962TA-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433fa9412f013fbe2d247a7bf5).(Infineon BTN8962 is a half of H-bridge IC)

As we all know,BDC driving circuit is just like this:
[image]

In this picture,We set a High side MOS(QA) as Open,and set a High side(QC) and a Low side(QB) MOSes as close.We just have to ouput a PWM signal to control the speed of BDC.
[image]
[image]
But when I use Infineon BTN8962,I found I cound not do this unless using the INH pin as PWM signal input pin.(But in fact,this pin is sleep mode enable pin.It can close its MOS.)

Which pin should I set as PWM signal output pin?

Comment: -1 for being stupid and posting this to meta.  Learn how a place works before barging in and engaging.

Comment: I am new in motor driving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INH** pin , should be tied to Vcc via a pull-up resistor.

The PWM should be supplied on the **IN** pin . you can also add a pull down here , to ensure the that incase of any failure in PWM , the input stays low .

Now in order to make a complete H bridge you would need 2 BTN8962 IC.

you have 3 options to drive them:

1. **Use 2 PWM signals .** Any driving method is possible in software.
2. **Use 1 PWM signal and a NOT gate** to generate the opposite in what is called locked antipahse.
3. **Use 1 PWM signal and 2 direction signals , use 2 AND gates** to connect the in what is called Sign magnitude drive.

choose depending on the availability of Pins in the micro-controller.

Comment: Tying the **INH** pin to GND turns the device off.

Comment: you are right , i meant it should be initially at ground and set high by micocontoller , i will update

Comment: I don't understand at all.In the Page 22 of the datasheet,if I want to drive this BDC in a direction,would I?:   1.Set the INH as HIGH    2.Set the IN(right) as HIGH      3.Set the IN(left) as PWM signal.       It's right?But,when the PWM signal is in HIGH level,the pMOS(left) is on.Will it cause a braking event?

Comment: my friend you didnot understand i simplied the answer, INH is always HIGH for both BTN8962 ICs. if you want to go right , set IN1 =0 , and IN2 PWM . if you want to go left , set IN2=0 , and IN1 to PWM.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: But,as we can see in P19,the Truth Table.When IN=1,HSS is ON and LSS is OFF.When IN=0,HSS is OFF and LSS is ON.As you say,if I want to go right,I set IN1=0 and IN2 PWM.In this situation,HSS1 is OFF and LSS1 is ON.At this time,when the PWM(IN2) is on the HIGH level,it is OK(HSS2 is ON and LSS2 is OFF).But when the PWM(IN2) is on the LOW level,the LSS2 is ON,will it cause a BDC motor brake event?(At that time,both LSS is ON)

Comment: Many information show that if I want to go right,I should keep the     LSS1 ON and keep the HSS1 and the LSS2 OFF.PWM to HSS2. When in the situation of BOTH LSS ON,it will cause a brake event

Comment: if IN1 =0 and IN2 =0 , the motor will brake. if you want to motor to coast ( which means no braking let it rotate freely until it is stopped ) then you should use INH1 or INH2 and turn off one side or both sides completely off